# Error after updating Apache on Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have an error after updating my packages. When trying to start my webserver, it throws the following error.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2    [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 84 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

And the Apache error log is (from file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Sat Aug 17 01:30:03 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.17RC1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Aug 17 01:41:38 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Aug 17 03:10:11.132425 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4182] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.1-2+debphp.org~raring+2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Aug 17 03:10:11.143718 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4182] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Aug 17 03:13:56.527245 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4182] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

What things do I have to do to recover or fix my server up?

Comment: show the config file in question...

Comment: also: what was the apache version before/after the update? where do the packages/files come from?

Comment: @sasivarmaKumar any luck?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Replace in apache2.conf:

```
LockFile /var/lock/apache2/accept.lock
```

with

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

Comment: Thanks for this fix....why is this necessary - what changes that makes this fix necessary??

Comment: I found some info here: [http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/Apache/Apache24Issues] "Apache has replaced the AcceptMutex, LockFile, RewriteLock, SSLMutex, SSLStaplingMutex, and WatchdogMutexPath directives with a single Mutex directive."

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is better to use a semaphore. Under Unix systems it is a lot faster and uses fewer resources.

And the option is just this:

```
Mutex sem
```